# Crash on GcmIntentService on Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I have implemented GcmIntentService for push notification everything was working fine but when updated version to Android 8 (Oreo) it is getting crash on oreo devices. Is it possible that I can continue uses of GcmIntentService for push notification.

Please share your view thanks in advance

Getting exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.PushNotificationReceiver: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.example
cmp=com.example/.pushnotification.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: 
app is in background uid UidRecord{635678a u0a186 RCVR bg:+1m44s591ms idle
procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

Comment: Is this still the actual GCM and not FCM?

Comment: yes AL, I am using CGM

Comment: Google already announced GCMs deprecation. Please proceed in migrating to FCM. Proceeding to use GCM may result to unexpected behaviors.

Comment: AL thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

> Google already announced GCMs deprecation. Please proceed in migrating to FCM.

AL is right, but GCM will only truly no longer work on April 11, 2019 as is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).

I believe the issue you faced is not related to this but rather, the fact that **you are attempting to start a background service from your receiver class**. Starting from Android 8, applications can no longer start background service when the application is not visible in the foreground.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all